# Open file with Adobe Captivate from command line

Tags: python, xml, operating-system, adobe

I am attempting to open an XML file with Adobe Captivate in my script using `os.system()`. Here is my code:

`os.system("open /Applications/Adobe\ Captivate\ 9/Adobe\ Captivate.app/ \"flashcards_template_changed.xml\"")`

It works fine the issue is with the opening screen on Adobe Captivate. When the program is run one of those 'New Document' windows pops up and asks you whether you want to start a new document, what kind of document, etc. Similar to Microsoft Word.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience bypassing this menu so the file would open. When I open Adobe Captivate and open my XML file it opens perfectly so I know it is in the right format.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If Adobe Captivate is registered as the default application for handling XML files, then you can leave out the application name altogether:

```
os.system("open flashcards_template_changed.xml")
```

Otherwise, specify the application with the `-a` flag:

```
os.system("open -a captivate flashcards_template_changed.xml")
```

I don't know for certain that "captivate" is a recognized name for Adobe Captivate; I'm just guessing, and I don't have access to a suitable Mac to find out.  If that doesn't work, you could probably use something very similar to what you had in your post:

```
os.system("open -a '/Applications/Adobe Captivate 9/Adobe Captivate.app' flashcards_template_changed.xml")
```

Comment: I tried the `-a` flag and it still opens with the little welcome window. If it helps at all, in order to open XML in Adobe Captivate you have to go to File > Import > XML. The default file type for Captivate is .cptx which is a Captivate Project file. In order to import XML you have to do it once the application is open.

Comment: I suppose `open` depends on the individual applications to support opening files from the command line, which they might not.